# Changing product based on user's location

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, third-party-plugin

Is it possible to change the products based on the local regions without choosing a particular store? So do, I need to make a custom field of location for the products?  Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly depends which attributes You want to change (description / translations / prices?) also depends on what regions (street / cities? depends on geoIP or shipping address?).

Please tell us more about You issue.

Basically you cant do that without store / store view.
May be there is some module doing something similar but I know know any.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I needed to make the entire product change based on the city. i'm wanted to implement a technique similar to [link to site](https://www.swiggy.com/) that accepts location from the user initially and then display on products available in the city

Comment: every city = different content?